# using icanhazip.com to find IP with mechanize in python, output not what I expected

Tags: python, networking, mechanize

I am using icanhazip.com to find my ip address. When I go to that site with a browser, my ip is output in a way I usually see it: 174.xx.xx.xx

When I use python and mechanize to get my ip from icanhazip.com, I get this result: 2001:4800:7810:512:13b2:ccd5:ff04:c5f4

I'm sure it's just a representation of the ip address in a way I have never seen. How do I convert that to the form that I am used to?

Thanks in advance.

```
In [9]: br.open("http://icanhazip.com/")
Out[9]: <response_seek_wrapper at 0x30bbe60 whose wrapped object = <closeable_response at 0x30bb0e0 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x2dd5ed0>>>

In [10]: br.open("http://icanhazip.com/").read()
Out[10]: '2001:4800:7810:512:13b2:ccd5:ff04:c5f4\n'

In [11]: print br.open("http://icanhazip.com/").read()
2001:4800:7810:512:13b2:ccd5:ff04:c5f4
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm the operator of icanhazip.com and I get this question a lot.  I have two additional DNS records that will help you get the result you want.  If you want to force an IPv4 lookup, use [ipv4.icanhazip.com](http://ipv4.icanhazip.com).  For IPv6, use [ipv6.icanhazip.com](http://ipv6.icanhazip.com).

If you access just [icanhazip.com](http://icanhazip.com), the result you see is dependent upon how your computer is configured to use IPv4 or IPv6 networking.  Most operating systems default to IPv6 (if it's available for use).

Comment: No problem. I should be offering it over HTTPS as well soon to make it easier to work around proxies. ;)

Comment: @majorhayden - # curl  https://ipv4.icanhazip.com/
curl: (51) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

Answer (score 2):

That's certainly IPv6, and there is no direct conversion to the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx format used in  IPv4, they are different addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's IPv6. See [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) for details.

What you'll get if try urlopen?

Comment: Thanks! I had no clue what it was other than probably hexadecimal numbers.